# how to compile multiple .cpp files together with main.cpp in Sublime text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext, build-system

I built a system in ST3 with the JSON script/command shown below to compile and run my C++ code(single file) by pressing CTRL+B previously and it worked. However, now I want to compile the other .cpp files(multiple files) and my main.cpp together which I believe this command/script is insufficient to do that. Therefore, I hope anyone here can teach me how to change the script/command which can allow people to compile multiple .cpp files together with main.cpp in ST3.

OR any other good suggestions.

I am really appreciate your help!
By the way I am using MinGW as the compiler

The command/script that I use

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"],
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name", "&&", "$file_path/$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you change your script in order to use `make` (or even better `cmake`) ?

Comment: @xorz57 i just started using ST3 this morning.... can you tell me more about "make" or "cmake"..... or do you have any example or links to show me? Thank you very much!

Comment: CMake is a build system generator used to produce "some kind of a recipe to build all your source files". Take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPMvU64RUTY . If things are too complicated for you then try searching for "GNU Make" on Google. I hope this helps.